# Flask url_prefix making duplicate url?

Tags: python, flask

I'm having some issues with using a flask url_prefix when submitting a form. It seems to be not be using the prefix when inside the template, and if I add the prefix manually it will duplicate the url_prefix.. Here is what I mean;

```
mod_auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')


@mod_auth.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home_page():
    if request.method == 'GET': # This works when navigating to /auth/signup
        return render_template('/auth/signup.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
       print('test')
       form_signup()
```

In my template..

```
<form action="/signup" method="post"> # This does not 
# work when submitting. It just trys to go to /signup not auth/signup
```

I've also tried;

```
<form action="auth/signup" method="post"> # This just 
#doubles the url it  produces.. auth/auth/signup ??
```

The blueprint is registered like;

```
from app.mod_auth.controllers import mod_auth as auth_module
app.register_blueprint(auth_module)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to find any info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use `url_for()` function:

```
<form action="{{url_for('mod_auth.home_page')}}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The template needed another forward slash..

```
<form action="/auth/signup" method="post">
```